# Знаки "Энтузиаст" и "Фанатик" в моб. приложении

Tags: поддержка, знаки

Будет ли считаться получения знаков за посещение сайта, если каждый день в мобильном приложении смотреть ленту новостей (Feed)? А вкладку Stack Overfow на русском?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, посещения с мобильного приложения считаются. Достаточно просмотреть любой вопрос или общую ленту вопросов.

Учтите, что дни посещения считаются не по вашему часовому поясу, а по универсальному глобальному времени. Его можно увидеть в меню "Достижения" в верхней части экрана.